# Convert Array into Key Value Pair array

Tags: php, arrays, key-value

I have a comma separated string which i explode into an array. If the array is of un-known length and i want to make it into a key value pair array where each element in the array has the same key, how do i do this? i'm assuming i'd have to use array_combine? can anyone give me an example using the array bellow? :

for instance:

```
array([0]=>zebra, [1]=>cow, [2]=>dog, [3]=>monkey, [4]=>ape)
```

into:

```
array([animal]=>zebra, [animal]=>cow, [animal]=>dog, [animal]=>monkey, [animal]=>ape)
```

Comment: array keys must be unique, please change the second code line

Comment: so.. there is no way to get an array into that format? Perhaps i used the wrong terminology? I thought i meant key-value pair.. but what i really am looking for is an array in the format of that in the second code line

Comment: "*same key*"? Is there any requirement to do so? It's not a feasible concept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use the same key for each element in your array. You need a unique identifier to access the value of the array. When you use animal for all, what value should be used? What you can do is to make a 2 dimensional array that you have an array inside an array:

```
array(
    [animals] => array(
        [0]=>zebra, [1]=>cow, [2]=>dog, [3]=>monkey, [4]=>ape
    )
)
```

this can be used with `$array['animals'][0]`

But still you need numbers or unique identifiers to access the values of the array.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
$string = 'zebra,cow,dog,monkey,ape';
$array = explode(',', $string);

$arrayReturn['animals'] = $array;

print_r($arrayReturn);
```

Comment: quote from OP. first sentence: "I have a comma separated string which i explode into an array."

Answer (score 0):

u cant have same key for all the values but u can do this

> lets say your string is

```
$a = 'dog,ant,rabbit,lion';
$ar = explode(',',$a);
$yourArray = array();
foreach($ar as $animals){
   $yourArray['animals']=$animals;
}
```

Now it doesnot matter how long your string is you will have you array as

> $yourArray['animals'][0]='dog'
>
> $yourArray['animals'][1]='ant'

....... so on ......